# Is there any way to get a Firebase ID Token without creating a user in Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I don't want my users to be created/managed in Firebase authentication, but at the same time I want to get a Firebase ID Token to access the Cloud Functions.

I have noticed that there are users found in the project settings that have specific permissions. [image: Service Account Users in Project Settings]

I wonder if we can create a valid Firebase ID token for those users to access the Cloud Functions without them being created in Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

No. A token belongs a specific user that exists in Firebase.

If you have your own authentication system then you can create [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) to login users with Firebase after authenticating the users yourself.
This still creates users in Firebase Authentication but not any other details like passwords. Make sure the Firebase Auth UID you set for users while creating custom tokens has a reference in your system too.

For Cloud Functions, you can add [`Cloud Functions Invoker`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?#cloudfunctions.invoker) role to those users. Easiest way to get user's access token would be to use `gcloud` CLI:

```bash
gcloud auth login

gcloud auth print-access-token
```

Then use the token in Authorization header:

```bash
curl --request GET \
  --url https://[CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_URL].cloudfunctions.net/function-name \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'
```

Comment: @AliOz are you trying to allow project members only to invoke a specific Cloud Function? In that case you can add "Cloud Functions Invoker" role to their emails [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam). They must be logged in with their Google Account and add relevant auth headers to invoke the function then.

Comment: I am trying to allow specific project members to invoke Cloud Functions without the need of an Firebase ID Token even though the CF is protected by a Bearer Token. If that's not possible, I want to get a Firebase ID Token for those users without the need of creating users for them in Firebase Authentication. Do you have any idea if that's possible?

Comment: @AliOz updated the answer. You won't need Firebase account if you just want to authorize users to call the function. Just add the invoker role and then users can use their access token to call the function.

Comment: I don't think this access-token can successfully pass the ```verifyIdToken()``` method provided by Firebase Admin SDK, right?

Comment: @AliOz no, the token I am referring to is not related to Firebase. For that you will need to create users in Firebase then.